# Change Day background color in Full Calendar using Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to change the background color of days in Full calendar control dynamically based on the events and the no.of hours those events occupy. Below is my sample code without my actual logic and just trying to see if it sets by default.

Saw few links which suggest to use `dayRender(date,cell)` but its giving error in angular and below code using `dayCellContent(date,cell)` is also giving error that css is not a function for cell.

How can we set background color for any specific date based on specific logic ?
[image]

Comment: That's correct. There is no `cell` argument to the dayCellContent function. Study https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection more carefully . Also to do what you're suggesting you probably need to use `dayCellDidMount` anyway, not `dayCellContent`.

Comment: P.S. Don't tag your question with multiple fullCalendar versions, especially as it's clear from the code that you aren't using any of them. I've corrected it - only tag the one you're actually using,

Comment: P.P.S. As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use below in Angular to show saturday and sunday in different colors in a month view

```
  dayRender: function (dayRenderInfo) {        
    let dateMoment = moment(dayRenderInfo.date);
    if (dateMoment.day() === 6 || dateMoment.day() === 0) {
      dayRenderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor = '#d6e7e1';
    }
    else {
      dayRenderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
    return dayRenderInfo;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @JapEvens, its working. One more thing which i need is how can I refresh or add colors dynamically based on events dragged by user. Example, if user drag drops and fill events more than 8hrs in a day, I want to change the background of that day to warn users that its going to overtime. 'dayRender' is loading all colors initially during the first load, but after initial load, will we have any other option to change the background colors ?  - Thanks in advance